# Where do I find amqp_userinfo of amqp_URI for connecting to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

So I'm trying connect to my local RabbitMQ server through a java application using the amqp_URI which is of the following format

```
amqp_URI       = "amqp://" amqp_authority [ "/" vhost ] [ "?" query ]
amqp_authority = [ amqp_userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
amqp_userinfo  = username [ ":" password ]
```

the question is where do I find the amqp_userinfo in my server for the connection. 
the user: guest and pwd: guest of the http://localhost:15672/ doesn't work. I have also tried creating a new user in http://localhost:15672/ and using it, it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got it, apparently the password length was too short, was successful when I created longer password for the user